# 32 amp charger on a 60 amp breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, nec

I installed a hardwired 32 amp EV car charger using a 60 amp breaker with 4 awg copper wire.  The electrical inspector failed me, concerned that the 32 amp charger should be on a 40 amp breaker.  Since the instruction booklet that came with the charger said the breaker had to be “at least 125%” of the 32 amp charger, I used a 60 amp breaker, to cover this charger, and allowing me to change to a higher amperage car charger in the future if needed.  I am trying to get a clarification from the EV charger company, but this is proving difficult.  Am I correct in using the larger breaker, since the code says at least 125%, not only 125%?

Comment: Can you link the booklet, or quote it fully?

Comment: It can be confusing, but you can also think of the 125% as being only allowed 80 % of the breaker rating.  With a 60 amp breaker, if something happens then the device could pull 28 extra amps into it before the breaker trips.  28 amps by 240volts can do quite a bit of heat(flames, melting, smoke) damage before the breaker trips.

Comment: My outdoor A/C unit has a maximum breaker size listed in the installation manual. I'm going to side with the inspector. Imagine if your car or charger is only rated for 40 amps but a malfunction happens and your car pulls 55 amps for an extended period. I know of a failed inspection for a dedicated air compressor circuit because the breaker was too large for the appliance.

Comment: Unless the inspector can provide a code reference (which may be local-only) for the decision, your setup is fine. You may or may not come out ahead if you contest it.

Answer (score 3):

#### NEC 110.2 you must use approved equipment (UL, CSA or ETL Listed).

#### NEC 110.3 you must follow labeling and instructions.

That is because when UL lists equipment they also approve the instructions which come with the equipment, and they make sure it is correct both for the equipment and the electrical code.

So make sure the unit is UL/CSA/ETL listed, and then read the instructions.  You must conform to those instructions.

#### Why is that important for EVSEs?

Because in [the EV charging standards](https://youtu.be/RMxB7zA-e4Y?t=584), the EVSE's job (aside from being a smart GFCI) is **to tell the car** how many amps are safe to pull.  The car's onboard computer goes "OK" and conforms with that.

Thus, **"amp rate" is a soft setting**. A great many EVSEs allow the installer to program it during Commissioning, so a single product can cover all applications.  For instance the Tesla Wall Connector 3.0 will cheerfully work at any ampacity setting from 15A to 60A. *

That means it has 60A internal wiring, and can be fed with a 60A breaker and wire, *even if it's clocked down to "40A"/32A actual in the soft settings*. *

However a true "40A"/32A max unit probably **does not have** 60A internal wiring, and would need a lower circuit breaker to protect a worst case scenario.

---

---

* Actual charge rate is 80% of that due to UL/NEC rules.

Answer (score 1):

The breaker needs to protect the wire **and the device**. Wire ampacities are standardized and 4 AWG copper is big enough for at least 70A, so that leaves the device.

Generally speaking, if the device doesn't specify then if it is a continuous type of device (like heater, EV charger, etc.) you add 25% and round up to the nearest standard size (15,20,25,30,40,50,60).There are certain special rules for large motors (not applicable here) and for certain cases combining things (two heaters, oven and cooktop etc not applicable here). Otherwise go with the default. Which in this case means 40A.

An interesting twist is EV chargers that can be set for different rates. If you have a charger that can go up to 48A then you need 60A wire and breaker to use it at full speed. But if you set it to 32A then you can use it with 40A wire and breaker. Same equipment just different configuration.

Oversizing the wire is 100% fine, as long as you don't run into the occasional problem of "wire too large to fit on breaker" or slightly more common "wire too large to fit on device". But oversizing the breaker is generally not a good idea.

Based on *typical* usage, 48A (maximum on a 60A breaker) really is more than most people need, though there are exceptions. However, oversizing the wire (with a smaller breaker now, larger in the future) does allow you to replace the EV charger with a *subpanel*. That would let you do things like:

- Use 32A/40A for charging and the remaining 20A for lighting, tools, etc. (That's 20A @ 240V so 40A @ 120V - which is enough for several circuits at typical usage.)
- Add a second EV charger. While the total you can use is still 48A (same 25% derate), you could program them to talk to each other (this is a standard function) and they will balance as needed based on the charging needed by each car. If they are roughly even, each might get 24A, but if one needs more than the other, it might be 32A and 16A or similar - all dynamically determined.

Comment: Standard sizes for fuses and fixed trip circuit breakers, per 240.6, are 40, 45, 50 and 60 why not simply change the breaker and get it approved.

Comment: By this same reasoning, devices that would go up in smoke if they drew a full 20 amps under some hypothetical fault condition could not be powered by a circuit with 20A rated breaker. Breakers/fuses in no way are intended to protect attached load equipment. That's the function of equipment internal breakers/fuses.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you fuse for the capacity of your wire.
If you have a #12 wire circuit feeding receptacles in your home the circuit is a 20 amp.
That does mean you you have to a have 20 amp load on what you plug into it. You can plug in several different devices until you exceed 20 amps then the breaker will trip off.
Again you fuse for the capacity of the wire your using.
Suppose you had 2 chargers, one for each vehicle you could use 2 30 amp chargers that could be fed from your 60amp amp circuit.
As a lineman you fuse for the capacity of the cable. If cable is rated for 300 amps than it is fused at 300 amps.

Comment: This is does not reflect the realities of the NEC at all. Read the top-ranked answer for why.